# Auto update comment count inside ajax prepended div

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, get

What I'm trying to do is auto update a comment count on any prepended div that has been constructed by ajax. So basically replacing the ajaxed response div *commentprint*

```
success: function(data) {
    $.each(data.posts, function(i, response) {
        $("#homestatusid").prepend("<div id='commentprint"+response['streamitem_id']+"'>Comments "+response['num']+"</div>")[
    }
});
```

I have a page called ajaxcommentcount.php. This is where the response would come from and replace *commentprint*. I just don't have any clue how to do it.

Comment: Sorry I dont see where this comment count is supposed to be added

Comment: I wanted to replace the div that has been prepended by ajax.  `<div id='commentprint"+response['streamitem_id']+"'>Comments "+response['num']+"</div>`

Comment: so i need to have some function that loads the ajaxcommentcount.php page in a setInterval and then somehow replace that newly inserted div. `<div id='commentprint"+response['streamitem_id']+"'>Comments "+response['num']+"</div>`

Comment: Then this question is Too Broad for this site as now its a _write something for me_ type question

Comment: Unless you show us some more of the code as what you show is a little specific and possibly unrelated

Comment: I#'m not asking anyone to write code for me. I'm asking how I'd go about catching the ajax div from another function like a normal function would on the client side code. Do I use find() or getElementbyid?

Answer (score 0):

Okay I was able to send the data needed and retrived and updated the ajaxed div.

I added the following to the success

```
timer = setInterval(function() {
        refreshCurrentTab(streamitem_id);
    }, 5000); refreshCurrentTab(streamitem_id);
```

And then called the function in .load() passing the post id over to return and replace the div.

```
 function refreshCurrentTab(streamitem_id)
    {
        $('#commentprint'+streamitem_id).load('ajaxcommentcount.php?var='+streamitem_id+'');
    }
```